# Multiple records with same id to make them NULL by Cursor

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have problem, need a solution for given example. The record count is 500k out of which a scenario is given below.

For example, we have following table where we have duplicate records. For each client, where duplication occurs the UID appended is the same as give before. But few of the total different records have same IDs. Such as Gail, Jacob and Kimberley having 111152 as same UID and Ritesh and Samuel has 111119.

```
FirstName       MiddleName    LastName    Phone    UID

Ainsley             J       Lee         354782      111153
Ainsley             J       Lee         354782      111153
Alexandros-Michail  Michail Charaktsis  234561      111154
chanthy                     lim         451897      111155
chanthy                     lim         451897      111155
chanthy                     lim         451897      111155
chanthy             Bbb     lim         451897      111155
Colin                       Mann        123456      111111
Emin                P       Halilovic   245124      111113
Emin                P       Halilovic   245124      111113
Emin                P       Halilovic   245124      111113
Gail                        Algewatta   124579      111152
Gail                        Algewatta   124579      111152
Jacob               Lin     John        965821      111152
Kimberley           J       Jones       985478      111152
Lauren                      Green       284531      111158
Lauren                      Green       284531      111158
Lauren                      Green       284531      111158
Lauren              M       Green       284531      111158
Linda               Ben     Edge        987456      111159
Linda               Ben     Edge        987456      111159
Mitchell            K       Kable       875492      111160
Mitchell            Kyle    Kable       875492      111160
Mitchell            Kyle    Kable       875492      111160
Mitchell            Kyle    Kable       875492      111160
Mitchell            Kyle    Kable       875492      111160
Ritesh              K       Khadgi      264518      111119
Samuel              P       Marshall    564823      111119
Samuel              peter   Marshall    564823      111119
Samuel              peter   Marshall    564823      111119
```

Now I have developed a cursor, where I need your help to find out those records and make their UIDs' NULL.
The Cursor is given below.

```
DECLARE @FirstName NVARCHAR(255),@MiddleName NVARCHAR(255),@LastName NVARCHAR(255),
        @DOB NVARCHAR(255), @Mobile FLOAT, @UID FLOAT
DECLARE @dt TABLE (UID NUMERIC(18,0), FirstName NVARCHAR(255), MiddleName NVARCHAR(255), LastName NVARCHAR(255))

--Cursor
DECLARE cursor1 CURSOR FOR
SELECT FirstName, MiddleName, LastName, DOB, Mobile, UID
FROM MAWork.dbo.gcs_customer_eight


OPEN cursor1
FETCH NEXT FROM cursor1
INTO @FirstName,@MiddleName,@LastName, @DOB, @Mobile, @UID
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN


IF EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM MAWork.dbo.gcs_customer_eight WHERE  ((@FirstName!=FirstName AND @LastName!=LastName AND @DOB!=DOB AND @Mobile!=Mobile) OR
                                                                            (@FirstName!=FirstName AND @MiddleName!=MiddleName AND @LastName!=LastName AND @DOB!=DOB AND @Mobile!=Mobile) OR
                                                                            (@FirstName!=FirstName AND @MiddleName!=MiddleName AND @LastName!=LastName AND @DOB!=DOB) AND @UID = UID ))
BEGIN

        INSERT INTO @dt 
        SELECT UID, FirstName, MiddleName, LastName FROM MAWork.dbo.gcs_customer_eight WHERE ((@FirstName!=FirstName AND @LastName!=LastName AND @DOB!=DOB AND @Mobile!=Mobile) OR
                                                                            (@FirstName!=FirstName AND @MiddleName!=MiddleName AND @LastName!=LastName AND @DOB!=DOB AND @Mobile!=Mobile) OR
                                                                            (@FirstName!=FirstName AND @MiddleName!=MiddleName AND @LastName!=LastName AND @DOB!=DOB) AND @UID = UID )

        --GOTO UpsertRecord
END
ELSE 
BEGIN
    GOTO NextRecord
END

/*UpsertRecord:
IF EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM @dt)
            UPDATE @dt SET UID = (SELECT TOP 1 UID FROM @dt )
        ELSE

        END

        DELETE FROM @dt
        GOTO NextRecord*/

NextRecord:
    FETCH NEXT FROM cursor1 
    INTO @FirstName,@MiddleName,@LastName, @DOB, @Mobile, @UID

END
CLOSE cursor1
DEALLOCATE cursor1
```

### END RESULT

The end result should be all those different clients having same UID, their UID should be removed and make it NULL.

Any help is much appreciable regarding.
Thanks.

Comment: Are you using MySQL or MS SQL Server? (Don't tag products not involved.)

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to process the data row by row.

To find and update all UID which belong to multiple names, you can execute something like below:

```
UPDATE <your table>
SET UID = NULL
WHERE UID in
(
    SELECT UID
    FROM <your table>
    GROUP BY UID
    HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT ... e.g. Full Name ...) > 1
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Update Table using the query below:

```
set UID=Null
where UID in
(select uid from
(select SELECT UID,row_number() over (partition by column1,column2,column3.. oreder by UID as rnm FROM table)res
    where res.rnm>1)
```

Answer (score 0):

try this one

UPDATE client SET UID = NULL WHERE UID in
(SELECT UID FROM client GROUP BY UID
    HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT Full Name,UID) > 1)